# An error when I add a variable to a string

Tags: php

I have this line of SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, ListStID, ListEmail, Title FROM $entry_database WHERE ID = '". $ReqBookID ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

As you can see, I am selecting an entry's ID, ListStID, ListEmail and Title Column if ID is equal to a string of numbers (or text), which is given by user in a form.

Everything is ok, and I don't get any syntax error when I write the code (I am using a code editor software. However, when I use it online, I get this error:

> Error: SELECT ID, ListStID, ListEmail, Title FROM WHERE ID = '4' You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID
>   = '4'' at line 1

I am very new to PHP, and I'm sure I am either adding extra ' or ", so I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this issue. I have tried the answers for similar questions, but no success yet.

Comment: `$entry_database` is empty, don't you see it? `... FROM WHERE ...` should be `... FROM `some_table `WHERE ...`

Comment: I am compelled to point out that you have the possibility of some SQL injection if $ReqBookID can be a malicious value.  You may also find that preparing the statement allows you to simplify how it works.

Comment: Either you didn't define `$entry_database` or you shouldn't have the `$` sign in there. I stand at being 50% right ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- 50% correct in this case!

Comment: HA HA HA!! The battle of teachers!! :P :P Thanks to both of you peeps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have empty `$entry_database` variable. As you see in error: `ListEmail, Title FROM WHERE ID` bewteen **FROM** and **WHERE** should be name of table. Proper syntax of SELECT:

```
SELECT columns FROM table [optional things as WHERE/ORDER/GROUP/JOIN etc]
```

which in your way should become:

```
SELECT ID, ListStID, ListEmail, Title FROM some_table_you_got WHERE ID = '4'
```

Comment: Ok,So that was my stupidity. The entry_database is the table name, I added the $ in error. Many thanks to you @Forien. Legend!!!

Comment: @Sep [**Just like I said...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302605/sql-syntax-error-mariadb-server-version-for-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-where#comment43068611_27302605) - wink.

Comment: LOL @Fred-ii- Another Awesome hint!! :) I appreciate the words of wisdom!! :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't suppose you know why my code is throwing error for the update by any chance? :) Thanks alot

Comment: @Sep Sorry, I don't.

Comment: @Sep now it seems that $ReqBookID is empty. In your $sql you see `''` instead of `'3286'` or anything

Comment: @Forien It worked!! You were right! I actually hadn't set it! Rookie Mistake!! :) Thanks alot for your help! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing your database name:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, ListStID, ListEmail, Title FROM ".$entry_database." WHERE ID = ". $ReqBookID .";
```

And make sure that $entry_database isn't null or empty:

```
var_dump($entry_database);
```

Also notice that you don't need to have $ReqBookID in '' as if it's an Int.

Comment: Inside double quotes, variables will be read.  So, his string was constructed fine as long as `$entry_database` is set.

Comment: Yeah I know, just my convention to always `".$variable."` things for legibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response @TimLewis, the entry_database is my table. I'm not sure why I had $ next to it. So how would you write the sql statement?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT ID, ListStID, ListEmail, Title FROM entry_database WHERE ID = ". $ReqBookID .";` Like that. Nice and simple!

Comment: @TimLewis the line you provided doesn't work. I think it's missing a " somewhere.

Comment: Oh it is. Oops. Remove the last `."` and it will work.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks Tim, I fixed it, and actually, following Forien response above, I found that I hadn't set the variable!! Thanks for all your help

Answer (score -2):

This problem also arise when we don't give the single or double quotes to the  database value.

**Wrong way:**

```
$query ="INSERT INTO tabel_name VALUE ($value1,$value2)";
```

As database inserting  values must be  in quotes **' '/" "**

**Right way:**

```
$query ="INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUE ('$roll_no','$name','$class')";
```

Comment: this answer is catastrophically wrong. you never add variables to the query in the first place, no matter with quotes or not