# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

Tags: php

this is the error i get... ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

my code looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$pid LIMIT 1";
```

I mean where can i find the manual? 
and what do i wrong?

Comment: _where can I find the manual_ => Google `mariaDB user manual`

Comment: I'm guessing `$pid` is empty, which will screw up your query. Drop the `LIMIT 1`, and see if the query works at all. You can also `echo $sql;` to see exactly what the query contains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL syntax error MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID = 4' at line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302605/sql-syntax-error-mariadb-server-version-for-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-where)